# Create the XML tag name dynamically in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a numeric parameter **numberOfFileds** with an integer number.
I need to create **numberOfFileds**+1 XML nodes with the following structure:

```
<CONT_CUST_FLD_00X>
    <xsl:value-of
            select="./platformCore:customField[@internalId='custrecord_ebiz_container_custfield_00X']/platformCore:value"/>
</CONT_CUST_FLD_00X>
```

where **X** - numbers from **0** to **numberOfFileds**

So, for example, when **numberOfFileds** = 3 the predictable output must be the following:

```
<CONT_CUST_FLD_000>
    <xsl:value-of
            select="./platformCore:customField[@internalId='custrecord_ebiz_container_custfield_000']/platformCore:value"/>
</CONT_CUST_FLD_000>
<CONT_CUST_FLD_001>
    <xsl:value-of
            select="./platformCore:customField[@internalId='custrecord_ebiz_container_custfield_001']/platformCore:value"/>
</CONT_CUST_FLD_001>
<CONT_CUST_FLD_002>
    <xsl:value-of
            select="./platformCore:customField[@internalId='custrecord_ebiz_container_custfield_002']/platformCore:value"/>
</CONT_CUST_FLD_002>
<CONT_CUST_FLD_003>
    <xsl:value-of
            select="./platformCore:customField[@internalId='custrecord_ebiz_container_custfield_003']/platformCore:value"/>
</CONT_CUST_FLD_003>
```

Please help me to implement this by writing appropriate xslt template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen a little bit another way of solving the issue:

Here is my template:

```
<xsl:template name="createFieldsAuto">
    <xsl:param name="newTagName"/>
    <xsl:param name="internaIdValue"/>
    <xsl:param name="numberOfFields"/>
    <xsl:param name="cycleIndex" select="0"/>
    <xsl:if test="number($cycleIndex) &lt;= number($numberOfFields)">
        <xsl:variable name="a" select="concat($internaIdValue, $cycleIndex)"/>
        <xsl:element name="{concat($newTagName, $cycleIndex)}">
            <xsl:value-of
                    select="./platformCore:customField[@internalId=concat($internaIdValue, $cycleIndex)]/platformCore:value"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="createFieldsAuto">
            <xsl:with-param name="newTagName" select="$newTagName"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="internaIdValue" select="$internaIdValue"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="numberOfFields" select="$numberOfFields"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="cycleIndex" select="$cycleIndex + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And here is the way I call it:

```
<!--the template below helps us to generate sections like these:-->

<!--<BILL_INFO_CUST_FLD_000 ></BILL_INFO_CUST_FLD_000 >-->
<!--<BILL_INFO_CUST_FLD_001 ></BILL_INFO_CUST_FLD_001 >-->
<!--<BILL_INFO_CUST_FLD_002 ></BILL_INFO_CUST_FLD_002 >-->

<!--example of using is the following:-->

<xsl:variable name="custFields_SH_CUST">
    <xsl:call-template name="createFieldsAuto">
        <xsl:with-param name="newTagName" select="'CONT_CUST_FLD_00'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="internaIdValue" select="'custrecord_ebiz_container_custfield_00'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="numberOfFields" select="9"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="$custFields_SH_CUST"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an *attribute value template* for the `name` attribute of `xsl:element` to create elements with calculated names.  I would approach the problem like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="platformCore:customField[
    starts-with(@internalId, 'custrecord_ebiz_container_custfield_')]">
  <xsl:element name="CONT_CUST_FLD_{substring-after(@internalId, 'custrecord_ebiz_container_custfield_')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="platformCore:value" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This could be a template rather than a for-each, of course.